# How to solve a large system of non-linear equations

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to solve Saha equations on Fe, which have 27 unknowns. Saha equations basically give you the ratios of the unknowns, but the unknowns are subject to constraints.

What function shall I use to solve this large system of equations?

Because each equation is only different by a parameter value, I do not want to type them one by one. So: Is there any easier way in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, preferably with an example with many fewer equations.

Comment: I imagine that you could use `NSolve` or `LinearSolve`, depending on the details of your equations.  Search Mathematica.StackExchange for ideas and examples.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I am wondering is there any easier way to key in equations to NSolve, say if I have 27 variables,ni i from 0 to 26, they all obey similar equations, can I just type in the general form of the equation and the constraint which is the sum of ni being some constant and ask NSolve to solve ni for me?

Comment: Please add at least a sample of your equations to the question.  It is very difficult to offer advice otherwise.

Comment: sum(ni)=1,sum(i*ni)=n0,n0*(ni+1)/ni=Ci, where ni ranges from n1 to n26, n0 is the 27th unknown, Ci are 26 known constants, I have 27 equations and 27 unknowns

Comment: @bbgodfrey sum(ni)=1,sum(i*ni)=n0,n0*(ni+1)/ni=Ci, where ni ranges from n1 to n26, n0 is the 27th unknown, Ci are 26 known constants, I have 27 equations and 27 unknowns

Comment: I count 28 equations, which is one too many for 27 variables.  Please clarify.

Comment: @bbgodfrey no, 27 eqns, the generic equation (ni+1)/ni constains 25 eqns with i from 1 to 25. because the numerator index cannot be larger than n26

Answer (score 1):

The generic equations to be solved are in the OP's Comments.  To answer the second question first, the equations can be written compactly as

```
imax = 26;
eqs = Table[n0 n[i + 1] == C[i] n[i], {i, imax - 1}];
var = Table[n[i], {i, imax}];
eqnrm = Sum[n[i], {i, imax}] == 1;
eqsum = Sum[i n[i], {i, imax}] - n0 == 0;
```

The first question is answered as follows.  In the absence of the last of these equations, the rest form a linear system which Mathematica can solve rapidly

```
slin = Solve[Join[eqs, {eqnrm}], var]
```

Not surprisingly, all elements of `var` are found to have a common denominator,

```
Denominator[slin[[1, 1, 2]]];
```

which can be used to simplify the remaining equation to a polynomial of order `imax` in `n0` before it is solved.

```
eqn0 = Simplify[First[First[eqsum] /. slin] Denominator[slin[[1, 1, 2]]]] == 0;
Solve[eqn0, n0]
```

With `n0` determined, the `var` follow immediately by back substitution.  The calculation takes a few minutes for `imax = 14` and progressively longer for larger values of `imax`.

**Addendum**

In answer to an additional question posed by the OP in a comment, back substitution is accomplished as follows.

The process above yields `imax` solutions for `n0`.  Presumably, physical considerations will guide the selection of which should be selected.  Suppose it is solution `2`.  Then, with `sn0` the list of solutions from the final `Solve` above,

```
j = 2; sn0j = sn0[[j]];
Table[Simplify[slin[[1, i, 2]] /. sn0j], {i, imax}]
```

accomplishes the back substitution.

Note, however, that this set of solutions rapidly becomes unmanageable in symbolic form for large `imax`.  Therefore, numerical values of `C` probably should be substituted into the equations from the outset, and the equations solved using `NSolve` rather than `Solve`.  If the `C` are functions of time, it may be better to determine the solutions for specific values of time and then, if desired, generate 'InterpolatingFunction`s rather than to attempt to obtain solutions symbolically as a function of time.  Only experimentation can answer which approach is superior.

Comment: how to do back substitution?

Comment: Please provide C (i), so that I can try to reproduce what you are doing.

Comment: Now, I have 26 equations only, I removed one constraint.

Comment: L = {7.9024, 16.1878, 30.652, 54.8, 75.0, 99.1, 124.98, 151.06, 233.6,
   262.1, 290.2, 330.8, 361.0, 392.2, 457, 489.256, 1266, 1358, 1456, 
  1582, 1689, 1799, 1950, 2023, 8828, 9277.69}
T = 10^7
lambda = (6.63*10^-34)/(2*3.1415926*9.10938291*10^-31*1.3806488*10^-23*T)^0.5
K = 2/lambda^3
ne = 10^11
imax = 26;
eqs = Table[
   ne n[i + 1] == 
    K*n[i] Exp[(L[[i]] - 
         L[[i + 1]])*1.60217657/(T*1.3806488*10^-4)] , {i, 
    imax - 1}];
var = Table[n[i], {i, imax}];
eqnrm = Sum[n[i], {i, imax}] == 10^6;
slin = Solve[Join[eqs, {eqnrm}], var];

Comment: I got error msg : RowReduce::luc: Result for RowReduce of badly conditioned matrix .... may contain significant numerical errors. >>